# paginatedlist throwing an error "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, iqueryable

I have looked here :
[LINQ To SQL exception: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712105/linq-to-sql-exception-local-sequence-cannot-be-used-in-linq-to-sql-implementatio)

and here :
[LINQ to Populate a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914638/linq-to-populate-a-range)

but I can't figure this one out. I have based my Task Manager on the NerdDinner project. Instead of FindUpcommingDinners I have a method below :

```
    Public Function FindAllTeamTasks(ByVal TeamRole As String) As IQueryable(Of Task) Implements ITaskRepository.FindAllTeamTasks

        Return From task In db.Tasks
               Join usrs In System.Web.Security.Roles.GetUsersInRole(TeamRole)
               On task.TaskAssignedToID Equals usrs
               Order By task.InsertDateTime _
               Select task
    End Function
```

When the result is passed into the Paginatedlist as source it errors with the "Local sequence cannot ..." error. The answer might be here as well but I can't figure it out. Please help.

[ASP.NET MVC2 LINQ - Repository pattern, where should the pagination code go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074894/asp-net-mvc2-linq-repository-pattern-where-should-the-pagination-code-go)

Comment: I've merged your unregistered account with your registered account. You can now accept the answer that you want to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the result of `GetUsersInRole()` in a join to a database table via LINQ to SQL. You can try this instead:

```
  Dim usrs = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetUsersInRole(TeamRole)

  Return From task In db.Tasks                      _
         Where usrs.Contains(task.TaskAssignedToID) _
         Order By task.InsertDateTime               _
         Select task
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your are using Linq to SQL, your query has to be able to be translated into SQL to be run against your database.  The Linq provider for Linq to SQL only knows how to do this for very certain operations that would occur outside the database.  So, for instance, Linq to SQL has no idea what to do with

```
Join usrs In System.Web.Security.Roles.GetUsersInRole(TeamRole)
```

because `GetUsersInRole` is not (as far as Linq is concerned) a table in the database, but rather a collection in your application.

As the error message mentions, there is an "exception" in that, in some cases, Linq to SQL does know what to do with Contains (by turning it into `IN` in SQL, if I recall) for a collection that does not reside in the database.  With that in mind, you might turn your query into something like (sorry it's in C#, but I hope you can translate):

```
string[] users = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetUsersInRole(TeamRole);

return db.Tasks
         .Where<Task>(t => users.Contains<string>(t.TaskAssignedToID))
         .OrderBy<Task, DateTime>(t => t.InsertDateTime)
         .AsQueryable<Task>();
```

Now, if your join was there because `TaskAssignedToID` was a collection and not merely a string (I'm not familiar with the model you're using, sorry), you might instead need to do something like

```
string[] users = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetUsersInRole(TeamRole);

return db.Tasks
         .Where<Task>(t => t.TasksAssignedToID.Any<string>(i => users.Contains<string>(i)))
         .OrderBy<Task, DateTime>(t => t.InsertDateTime)
         .AsQueryable<Task>();
```

I'm not 100% sure that Linq to SQL is fine with Any -- I work mostly with Linq to Entities -- but I hope this makes some sense.

Comment: It should be "task.TaskAssignedToID" (no "s") and it isn't an enumerable (can't use "Any()").